# ¿Existe alguna herramienta para mejorar la ortografía en stackoverflow en español?

Tags: discusión, advertencias-en-preguntas, enseñanza-aprendizaje

Quizás esta pregunta ya se haya realizado, quizás no le den importancia, pero yo siempre veo preguntas y respuestas con faltas de ortografía (yo mismo tengo muchas -lo siento-).

Me pregunto por qué StackOverflow no utiliza alguna herramienta que prohíba la publicación de preguntas y respuestas cuando la ortografía de las mismas sea incorrecta (según las reglas del español), pensé que quizá no tenían y  busqué en internet algunas herramientas que podrían ayudarnos a los usuarios con la ortografía, y encontré estas:

[Herramienta en línea 1](https://languagetool.org)
o 
[Herramienta en línea 2](https://www.correctoronline.es/)

La primera es una extensión que se puede instalar en el navegador, tal vez podríamos recomendar esta u otra mejor que uds. conozcan.

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Existe alguna herramienta en desarrollo o ya implementada en el sitio?
- ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Encontré rápidamente al menos unos diez errores de gramática y ortografía en esta pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz mmm donde? en que parte?

Comment: ¿Quieres que haga una edición y corrija todos los errores que encontré?

Comment: La ortografía se mejora leyendo. Simple. Para eso cualquier usuario puede editar la pregunta y corregir lo que esta mal escrito.

Answer (score 4):

Pensar en darle al usuario incluso una herramientas para que mejore su ortografía, me parece algo no estrictamente necesario.

Lo anterior, por que estamos en una comunidad que busca apoyar en la resolución de dudas en la programación de software; por lo cual darles incluso una herramienta para aprender a escribir se me hace un tanto ilógica.

Por otro lado, sería un trabajo descomunal, considerando que por ejemplo:

En el español de Argentina, `vos` es correcto y parte del idioma regional **(esto es solo un ejemplo)**

Mientras que en el español usado en México no se maneja, por lo cual el corrector de no tener una correcta distinción entre expresiones por países terminaría marcando como incorrecta dicha palabra.

Por otro lado pensar en el hecho de que se le ayude al usuario con un corrector me suena a hacerle mas mal que bien, explico:

1. La mayoría de los usuarios de esta plataforma, tienen perfil o de universitario o de profesional que ya labora
2. Considero que es encaminar los esfuerzos del editor de textos a convertirlo en un `Word` lo cual no me hace sentido
3. La red de `StackExhange` ya cuenta con sitios muy similares a dicha funcionalidad, es decir mas que corrector; es conocer sobre el lenguaje; tales como:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Opino que la ortografía igual que la programación solo se pule practicándola, ¿cómo? sencillo, mira:

1. lee libros (físicos ó e-book)
2. lee la documentación traducida de las herramientas que usas
3. consulta regularmente un diccionario
4. lee noticias en internet

**Mi experiencia como docente me demuestra que...**

> Un alumno o alumna que deja la responsabilidad de la ortografía de su
>   escrito a un software generalmente va a tener errores por que
>   retomando lo de los regionalismos, me dicen *hay profe pero por que
>   Word no me lo reconoce como error  no es mi culpa* entonces mejor que
>   aprendan de ortografía donde corresponde

Comment: en la parte que comentas el sitio de spanish yo principalmente veo que son extrangeros los que estan ahi y no nativos yo estoy para ayudar o buscar alguna duda y  con los puntos mencionado anteriormente siendo honesto no creo que lo hagan yo si leeo libros PDF y la docs pero en ingles,etc pero quiza se necesite orientar algunos usuarios que  posiblemente sean jovenes de 14-15 que alla aqui ( te lo puedo asegurar porque amigos mios de secundaria se encuentran aqui - no dire nombres), pero porque crees  que seria complicado por las regiones de cada pais?

Comment: imagina de secundaria y con faltas de ortografía, no amigo, **SO en español** es para ayudar con dudas de software; si tus amigos necesitan redactar mejor, que tomen clases de español y de ortografía @simon

Comment: bueno solo digo en general :P  pero mi profesor de software en la universidad nos enseña sobre el desarrollo  de proyectos impresos con buena ortografia y por eso lo comento, alguna  persona tienen mala ortografia no es pecado pero si es algo malo en el mundo laboral , yo solo opinio esta idea por si alguien tiene alguna idea de desarrollar alguna herramienta similar :P como yo ando desarrollando un herramienta algo simple que permita traducir español mexicano a ingles formal americano para Stackoverflow en español :P luego se los comparto el repo

Comment: , pero por eso les pregunto :P pero si tu opinas que es una idea no fiable ps :(

Answer (score 1):

En Meta SE existe un solicitud (feature request) que data del 2009, [Please add a spell checker to the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3932/289691), la cual aún no tiene ninguna etiqueta de estado.

En algunos comentarios y respuestas a la citada solicitud se menciona que la funcionalidad de corrector ortográfico es mejor que se implemente a nivel del navegador. Hoy en día algunos navegadores como Chrome ya incluyen un corrector ortográfico si este no fuera suficiente podrías usar alguna extensión, sin embargo, esto no sustituye el estudiar ortografía y gramática.

Answer (score 1):

En el fondo, lo que piden de las preguntas es que se entienda lo que se está preguntando. Si ni por error trae un punto o una coma, seguramente la votaran negativa o la dejarán en espera mientras se deshace el entuerto; creo que este sería un deseable bonito que con algún plugin en el navegador se mejora para cada quien.